# Checking if Nodes are SKShapeNodes

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, xcode6.4

In my simple game, I need to remove all SKShapeNodes before the next step happens. Here is the code that I have:

```
for child in self.children(){
    if(child==SKShapeNode(){
        child.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

This does not work because Xcode does not know what to do with child's class. Xcode wants me to add

```
as! NSObject
```

after child to "force downcast". This also does not work. I think that this is because now, child will always be an NSObject, not an SKShapeNode.

How do I fix this? I am sure that it is very simple but I cannot seem to fix this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as follows:

```
for child in parent.children //in you case, self is the parent
{
    if let child = child as? SKShapeNode
    {
        child.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```